# Wpf ListView Grouping

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I've been trying to replicate the Listview like the screenshot below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yem4K.png)

But my problem is I can't make it work. I'm pretty new to MVVM

This is my xaml code

```
<ListView Margin="10,10,10,6" x:Name="BusinessListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Company}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding BusinessType}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

And below is my viewmodel code

```
List<BusinessM> businesses = new List<BusinessM>();
businesses.Add(new BusinessM
{
    BusinessType = "Enterprise",
    ListBusiness = new List<BusinessInfo>
    {
        new BusinessInfo {Company = "Microsoft"}
    }
});

BusinessListView.ItemsSource = businesses;
```

Model

```
public class BusinessM
{
    public string BusinessType { get; set; }
    public List<BusinessInfo> ListBusiness { get; set; }

    public BusinessM()
    {
        ListBusiness = new List<BusinessInfo>();
    }
}
public class BusinessInfo
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the program it returns an error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Company' property not found
```

What's wrong with my code? What I understand is I'm not referencing properly the property Company into the Listview?

If it's that's the case. How can I do it properly. I've been trying to solve it myself but I can't make it work.

Thank you.

Comment: Your `ListView` is bound to a `List` of `BusinessM`, and `BusinessM` doesn't have any `Company` property. Basically, you have a `List` of `List`, which is hard to handle in a simple `ListView`. I don't know what you really want to achieve, but I think there is a confusion with the Group and the different lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error specified because of the way your data structure is bounded to listview's item source property. Typically, you would have a flattened list of model and then you would use `ColllectionViewSource` to apply Grouping and/or Sorting on the collection.

In posted code, you are binding ItemSource to list of `BusinessM` which means each list view item represents object of type `BusinessM`. So when you bind `GridViewColumn` to `Company`,it expects `BusinessM` type to have a property with similar name, which by the way, is not the case.

I have modified you code so that I can explain you how it should be done (IMO) with example.

**Model:**

```
public class BusinessM
{
    public string BusinessType { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

**Code behind (xaml.cs):**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        cvs.Source = GenerateData();
        cvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(BusinessM.BusinessType)));
        BusinessListView.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
    }

    private List<BusinessM> GenerateData()
    {
        List<BusinessM> businesses = new List<BusinessM>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                businesses.Add(new BusinessM
                {
                    BusinessType = $"Type {i}",
                    Company = $"{i}{j}"
                });
            }
        };

        return businesses;
    }
}
```

**View (xaml):**

```
<ListView Margin="10,10,10,6" x:Name="BusinessListView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Company" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Company}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding Name}">
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```